# Android: Communicate with printer using USB to LPT adapter

Tags: android, printing, adapter, lpt

My Android software need to talk with a Zebra printer using an USB-to-Parallel(LPT) adapter. I don't know if I have to consider the adapter as a Usb/serial interface or a Parallel connection. I don't think that Android can handle LPT connections; on the other hand, if I consider it as a serial connection, I can see its endpoints but I am not able to write because a lack of information about the adapter(Baud rate, data bits...). 
Someone has experience with LPT connections and Android? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are no drivers for USB-to-Parallel(LPT) adapter in Android. But You can use:

1) [printing from Android to a Bluetooth Zebra printer](https://developer.zebra.com/thread/29780);

2) [USB Zebra print station](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/print-station-ug-en.pdf)

3) [Zebra with WiFi](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/printer/zq110-android-sdk-api-ug-en.pdf)

4) [Zebra with serial port](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zm400/ZM_Serial_Comm.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. I have used these softwares and the Zebra SDK with recent printers but I have a lot of old printers that can use only LPT (for instance Zebra LP 2824). All those softwares cannot see my LPT printers connected via the adapter. Windows recongnize it as a IEEE 1284 device so i can install it and use it...but not Android. I used the Zebra SDK in some apps to talk to printers but it does not work with LTP.

Comment: So You can use them from Android via Windows PC as network printers. And seems  Zebra LP 2824 has [serial interface](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7531&actp=LIST) with The printer default serial port settings are 9600 baud, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity.  For Flow Control both DTR and XON/XOFF are active all the time. [Hardware and Software flow control](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/eltron/epl_setting_com.htm) so You can use it as serial via USB-RS232 OTG adapter.

Comment: Yes, the guide refers to the RS232 version of the printer: there are 3 versions of LP 2824 1-RS232/USB; 2-Parallel(LPT); 3-Ethernet. I have some Lp 2824 (RS232 version) and the communication via serial works perfectly. Unfortunately with the LPT version the same approach does not work. I'll keep trying and I will update this page.

Comment: May be serial-to-parallel adapter like [that](http://www.learningelectronics.net/circuits/serial-to-parallel-converter.html) will solve your problem.